# Array Index out of bound exception using jblas

Tags: matrix, indexoutofboundsexception, java

```
       double [][] AdjacencyMat = new double[baseSize][baseSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < baseSize; ++i)
        {
            for (int j =0; j < baseSize; ++j)
            {
                AdjacencyMat[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        DoubleMatrix matrix = new DoubleMatrix(AdjacencyMat);
```

I am trying to JBLAS for my matrix operations. In the following code, I am getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0  
at org.jblas.DoubleMatrix.<init>(DoubleMatrix.java:370)
```

What I am doing wrong ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: First of all, you will need to tell us what is on line 370 in `DoubleMatrix.java` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As opposed to creating a new matrix and filling it with zeros you can use the static factory method in the `DoubleMatrix` class like this

```
DoubleMatrix matrix = DoubleMatrix.zeros(baseSize, baseSize);
```

This is a way of getting around your problem. See the [javadoc](http://jblas.org/javadoc/org/jblas/DoubleMatrix.html) for more cool stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to assign 0 to your elements at all.

```
double[][] a = new double[10][10];
```

will itself create array will all the elements as 0.0 by default.